# Datadog Grok Parsing - extracting fields from list of JSON

Tags: json, parsing, datadog, grok

I want to extract fields from list of json

```json
[
  {
    "ExecMainStartTimestamp": "Wed 2021-10-27 11:31:36 UTC",
    "hostname": "i-XX",
    "_time": "2021-10-27 12:20:01",
    "ASG": "prod1",
    "ExecMainPID": "1447",
    "Names": "nginx.service",
    "LoadState": "loaded",
    "ActiveState": "active",
    "UnitFileState": "enabled"
  },
  {
    "ExecMainStartTimestamp": "Wed 2021-10-27 11:31:46 UTC",
    "hostname": "i-XX",
    "_time": "2021-10-27 12:20:01",
    "ASG": "prod1",
    "ExecMainPID": "1669",
    "Names": "gunicorn.service",
    "LoadState": "loaded",
    "ActiveState": "active",
    "UnitFileState": "enabled"
  }
]
```

Can someone help me to do this in datadog grok pipeline?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.